# Chrome has “Failed to load PDF document” error message on inline PDF with using PHPExcel

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf, pdf-generation, phpexcel

I have a problem with reading pdf file in Chrome by using PHP and generated by PHPExcel Library. its working in Firefox properly but not working in chrome. please help me

The following code is how I do in PHP

```
    require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
    $rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
    $rendererLibrary = 'dompdf';

     $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

        //  set the paper size and the paper view style
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A4);

        //  make cell content text-align center
        $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
                    ->getAlignment()
                    ->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

        //  border for all cells
        $styleArray = array(
                        'borders' => array(
                            'allborders' => array(
                                'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
                            )
                        )
                    );
        $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray($styleArray);

        // Set document properties
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Occasional Riot")
                                     ->setLastModifiedBy("Occasional Riot")
                                     ->setTitle("Interest Area Document")
                                     ->setSubject("Interest Area List")
                                     ->setDescription("The list of the Interest Area")
                                     ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                                     ->setCategory("Interest Area file");

        foreach(range('B','F') as $columnID) {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)
                ->setAutoSize(true);
        }
        // Add some data
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->setCellValue('A1', 'Social')
                    ->setCellValue('H2', 'Venue');

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A1:B1');



        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getFont()->setBold(true);


        if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
                $rendererName,
                $rendererLibraryPath
            )) {
            die(
                'NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
                '<br />' .
                'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure'
            );
        }

        // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (PDF)
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Interest Area.pdf"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
        $objWriter->writeAllSheets();
        $objWriter->save('php://output');

        $objWriter->save('interest.pdf');
        readfile("interest.pdf");
        exit;
```

Comment: Can you post the chrome error message? You can check it using developer console

Comment: @rajeshujade : console message is null.. while in whole page  it prints “Failed to load PDF document” message

Comment: @Let me know PHPExcel library version?

Comment: PHPExcel  library version is **1.7.9**

Answer (score 3):

Little late to the party, but just had a similar error.

I had to populate a PDF with PHP and show it after, but I was always getting a "Failed to load PDF document" error from Chrome.

I don't know if it was the same problem, but in my case, PHP was reporting Notice and Warning errors, nothing too important, but because of that, the PDF was not able to load. Hiding the error solved my problem!

TL;DR : Try `error_reporting(E_STRICT);` on top of your PHP file (quick and dirty) or `exit;` before your `readfile("interest.pdf");` so you can see the errors and fix them.